# Solution of non-convex smooth function with non-convex constraints

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following minimization problem 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x,y}{\text{minimize}}
& & H(x,y) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f(x,y) \leq \lambda
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where $H = ||t -\sum_k x_{k}f(y_{k}) - \sum_k x_{k}y_{k}||_2^2$ is smooth, non-convex function and $f = |\sum_k x_{k}f(y_{k})|$ is non-smooth, non-convex function, but it is convex if we keep one variable constant. I was thinking of using Proximal Alternating Linearized Minimization, is this a valid approach? Is there any other approach to solve the above problem? A related problem is [Proximal operator of multiplication of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810782/proximal-operator-of-multiplication-of-two-variables)

Comment: Are $x,y$ reals?  Or vectors?

Comment: @Michael $x$ and $y$ are vectors

Comment: Too general. Give us $H$ and $f$.

Comment: A special case of your problem is the unconstrained minimization of a non-convex function $H(x)$ for a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and there is no efficient solution for that general problem. If $x,y$ were scalars and $H$ is Lipschitz continuous, I would suggest discretizing the space $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ into squares of size $\epsilon^2$ and testing all $1/\epsilon^2$ grid points.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I wanted to know if there exists a general algorithm for solving such class of problems. Edited the question.